# how to create a loop that ends with "done" python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to create a program that uses a list to store the names of some notable celebrities. I need to to use a loop to prompt the user for the names and to add them to the list. When the user enters "done" the loop should stop. The program should then output the number of celebrities entered. Finally, the program should use another loop to display the celebrity names, each on its own line, and "done" should NOT be in the celebrities list where did I go wrong here because it shows the "celebrite name" over and over again.
This is what my professor had to say about it if this helps any.

Your celebrity program really needed more context. I looked at your code and could tell what to do, but to a user it showed celebrity name over and over again.

```
list = []
while(1):
    name = input("enter celebrity name:") 
    if name == "done":
        break;
    else:
        list += [name] 

print(len(list))

for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
```

Comment: Im wondering what I did " or did not do " that he didn't like.   I passed with what I did I just wanna know what I could have done to make this more accurate so I can learn from it

Comment: See my answer for some suggestions.

Comment: While JB333 has some good pointers, I'm pretty sure your professor's complaint is really that, while your program works, it doesn't provide a very good user experience. The user has to simply *know* that typing the word "done" causes the loop to break and finish the program. You should tell the user that somehow. Otherwise, they might just think it's a program that does nothing but print "enter celebrity" over and over. Try to adopt the uninitiated user's perspective.

Comment: @JB333 - he is using python 3 - so raw_input does not exist.

Comment: All I know is is that's what he replied with and when I've emailed him in the past its taken weeks for him to reply ( its a online course) Im just curious as to what the " more context" is that he was wanting.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 good call on the `raw_input`. Since your answer below does a good job summarizing I've removed my comment

Comment: use the `.append` method instead of `+= []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok :

1. Never use list as a variable name - it is bad form, and will get you into trouble eventually.
2. There is a simpler way to loop around the content of a list, you don't need to use the index.
3. Your program does not tell the user how to use the program, or how to stop entering names - maybe your professor was suggesting your program should generate some useful instructions. Also when it finishes it just prints a number, and a list of names, maybe some useful info there would help too.
4. It is better practice to use `While True`, rather than `while (1)` in Python.

for number 2 - what does this code do :

```
a=["a","b","c","d","e"]
for i in a:
    print (i)
```

Comment: NP, good job summarizing improvements here. Looking at it again it is probably mostly number 3 that the professor was noting on. No matter how good your code is, if the user doesn't know how to use it, it has no value!

Comment: @JB333 - I agree - I think it is #3 which is the focus of the profs concerns, but I would suggest that a learner should be doing both usability and code quality

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about this from the user's point of view. Let's run your code and see how it looks on the console:

```
enter celebrity name:Celeb 1
enter celebrity name:Celeb 2
enter celebrity name:Celeb 3
enter celebrity name:Celeb 4
enter celebrity name:Done
enter celebrity name:DONE
enter celebrity name:Celeb 5
enter celebrity name:done
7
Celeb 1
Celeb 2
Celeb 3
Celeb 4
Done
DONE
Celeb 5
```

Great. It starts by asking me to input a celebrity name. Once that is done and I press enter, it asks the exact same thing. Over and over. There is no instructions for the user. How do they know when to end? How many do I need to enter? Is there an error because it keeps saying `enter celebrity name:` repeatedly? Did I do something wrong?

Next, notice that I typed `Done` and `DONE`, both had an unexpected result. It continued the program. An option to get around this is

```
if name.lower() == "done":
```

Using this, you always check if the lower case version of the input text is `done`.

Next, you spit out a number. `7`. What does this mean? Add something descriptive to your print statement:

```
print("You input {} celebrities!".format(len(list)))
```

Finally, your list of celebrities. What is this telling the user? Provide some context to your output.

---

Some code criticism:

- You use the variable `list`. Don't use a [reversed word](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#). (IE. `celebrities_list`)
- Your loop at the end is overly complicated. You can loop through the list without using `range` (indexes)

For example:

```
for c in celebrities_list:
    print(c)
```

Comment: reversed word?? like `tsil`? :) Technically `list` is not reserved (otherwise it would be a syntax error). You are correct that it's a bad idea though